# Match a column header (of nonspecific location) against column contents, and get all row headers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am using Excel 2016 on Windows 8.1.

I want to be able to match two criteria, where one criterion is a column header and the other is cell contents that can occur any number of times within that column, and return multiple row headers as results.

In my example, I want to be able to input the name of a fruit (the column headers) and a quality ('good' or 'bad') in cells B6 and B7, and receive whichever characteristics (row headers) match that fruit and quality. If I give it 'apples' and 'good', I want it to return 'appearance' and 'flavour' (and not 'price'), for example.

I've used Index Match before, and I've heard of using array formulas to work with ranges of cells. But I can't work out how to combine all this - especially as all the tutorials I've found have been about how to match against a row header and a column header, and find the resulting cell(s). Plus, I don't want to 'hard-code' a reference to a given column header because I might not always want to match 'Apples'.

I have tried a pivot table and it wasn't very elegant (my real data has 5 'quality' items, not just 2).

[Screenshot of example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF4jk.png)

```
   A           B         C        D         E        F
1            | Apples | Bananas | Lemons | Mangos | Oranges
-----------------------------------------------------------
2 Appearance | good   | good    | bad    | bad    | good
 ----------------------------------------------------------
3 Flavour    | good   | good    | bad    | good   | good
 ----------------------------------------------------------
4 Price      | bad    | good    | good   | bad    | good
----------------------------------------------------------
5            |        |         |        |        | 
----------------------------------------------------------  
6 Fruit:     | apples |         |        |        |
----------------------------------------------------------
7 Quality:   | good   |         |        |        |             
----------------------------------------------------------
8            |        |         |        |        |     
----------------------------------------------------------  
9 Results:   |        |         |        |        |         
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If there are two or more, how do you want the output? In one cell or is many fine?

Comment: In many cells is fine (in fact, I'd prefer that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation on what @Scott Craner proposed, but it may work for you.

[image: Column contents to row headers]

I added placeholders for additional qualities.  Put this formula in B11 and then drag down for a number of rows to equal the number of qualities you have.

`=IF(INDEX($B2:$F2,,MATCH($B$8,$B$1:$F$1))=$B$9,$A2,"")`

If you don't like the look of Results1 and really want the values to be in one cell, then put this formula in B18 and hide rows 11 through 15.

`=IF(B11="","",B11&"//") & IF(B12="","",B12&"//") & IF(B13="","",B13&"//") & IF(B14="","",B14&"//") &  IF(B15="","",B15&"//")`

Substitute whatever you want as a separator for "//".

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate through the cells and return all row numbers that match to the INDEX which will then return the value.

Put this in B9:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$4)/(($B$2:$F$4=$B$7)*($B$1:$F$1=$B$6)),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

And copy over enough to account for all the characteristics.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately it doesn't output all of the relevant row headers - it outputs 'Appearance' (which is correct) but doesn't output 'Flavour'. I did try copying it across but it only outputted blanks afterwards.

Comment: @InskoraBournvadus when you copy across are you dragging across or are you copying the formula itself from on cell to the next.  It is working for my, as you can see in the photo above.